# Saving my array/ dictionary or array of dictionaries to core data

Tags: arrays, json, core-data, dictionary

I have an array that I get as a Json string that I put into an array of dictionaries below

```
 {
        StockData =     (
                    {
                Id = 3;
                Name = Banana;
                Price = "1.5";
                Requests = "";
                Size = 1Kg;
                Subname = "";
                Type = Fruit;
            },
                    {
                Id = 4;
                Name = Carrot;
                Price = 2;
                Requests = "";
                Size = 1Kg;
                Subname = "";
                Type = Vegetable;
            },
                    {
                Id = 15;
                Name = Kiwi;
                Price = "1.3";
                Requests = "";
                Size = 1kg;
                Subname = "";
                Type = Fruit;
            },
                    {
                Id = 5;
                Name = Parsnips;
                Price = "1.75";
                Requests = "";
                Size = 1kg;
                Subname = Large;
                Type = Vegetable;
            },
                    {
                Id = 14;
                Name = s;
                Price = 0;
                Requests = "";
                Size = s;
                Subname = s;
                Type = s;
            },
                    {
                Id = 13;
                Name = a;
                Price = 0;
                Requests = "";
                Size = a;
                Subname = a;
                Type = a;
            },
                    {
                Id = 12;
                Name = Brocoli;
                Price = 2;
                Requests = "";
                Size = 1Kg;
                Subname = "";
                Type = Vegetable;
            }
        );
    }
```

The following method then gets called. I take the NSManagedObjectSubclass (StockArray) and try to take the attributes from the data model and fill them with the contents from the array.

```
+ (StockArray *)stockWithStockInfo:(NSDictionary *)stockInfo
                inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context


    {
        StockArray *stock = nil;

        MySingletonCentre *tmp = [MySingletonCentre sharedSingleton];





        NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"StockData"];
        //NSLog(@"Log request %@", request);
        request.predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"unique = %@", [tmp.stockDict objectForKey:@"Id"]];
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

        NSError *error =nil;
        NSArray *matches = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        if(!matches || ([matches count] > 1)){
            NSLog(@"Log StockArray+Stock.h%@", @"error");
            // NSLog(@"Log stock array??????1 %@", stock);
        }



        else if
            ([matches count] ==0){
            stock = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"StockData" inManagedObjectContext:context];
         NSLog(@"Log %@", stock);


            stock.unique = [tmp.globalStockArray valueForKeyPath:@"Id" ] ;
            //
            stock.type =[tmp.globalStockArray valueForKeyPath:@"Type"];
            stock.name =[tmp.globalStockArray valueForKeyPath:@"Name"];
            stock.subName =[tmp.globalStockArray valueForKeyPath:@"Subname" ] ;
            stock.price =[tmp.globalStockArray valueForKeyPath:@"Price"];
            stock.size =[tmp.globalStockArray valueForKeyPath:@"Size"];
            stock.requests =[tmp.globalStockArray valueForKeyPath:@"Requests"];
```

Once that is done the items are in what I believe to be the right format for core data???

```
data: {
    name = "(\n    Banana,\n    Carrot,\n    Kiwi,\n    Parsnips,\n    s,\n    a,\n    Brocoli\n)";
    price = "(\n    \"1.5\",\n    2,\n    \"1.3\",\n    \"1.75\",\n    0,\n    0,\n    2\n)";
    requests = "(\n    \"\",\n    \"\",\n    \"\",\n    \"\",\n    \"\",\n    \"\",\n    \"\"\n)";
    size = "(\n    1Kg,\n    1Kg,\n    1kg,\n    1kg,\n    s,\n    a,\n    1Kg\n)";
    subName = "(\n    \"\",\n    \"\",\n    \"\",\n    Large,\n    s,\n    a,\n    \"\"\n)";
    type = "(\n    Fruit,\n    Vegetable,\n    Fruit,\n    Vegetable,\n    s,\n    a,\n    Vegetable\n)";
    unique = "(\n    3,\n    4,\n    15,\n    5,\n    14,\n    13,\n    12\n)";
})
```

I have been trying for about five days now and after reading and watching many tutorials I still cant find what to do. I am wondering if the format is wrong. Seems like I am so close as both formats above seem to show data in the correct fashion.

I have only been coding for four months and I have only finished one app so it is still quite the learning curve for me.

Not only am I not sure which format is the one to use, I also want to know the method to save.

I now have the following code, It saves, but saves it all to one row. 
If I put a log in the "for (NSDictionary *dict in self.arrayToUseOnTableView)"  loop then the log brings me back the same amount of logs that are in the array but it would seem that instead of giving it an entity for each dictionary it lumps them in one.

```
-(void) saveJSONToCoreData{

    Stock *stock = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    stock = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Stock" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    // NSLog(@"Logstock 1 %@", stock);

    for (NSDictionary *dict in self.arrayToUseOnTableView)
    {


        stock.unique = [self.arrayToUseOnTableView valueForKeyPath:@"Id" ] ;
        stock.type =[self.arrayToUseOnTableView valueForKeyPath:@"Type"];
        stock.name =[self.arrayToUseOnTableView valueForKeyPath:@"Name"];
        stock.subName =[self.arrayToUseOnTableView valueForKeyPath:@"Subname" ] ;
        stock.price =[self.arrayToUseOnTableView valueForKeyPath:@"Price"];
        stock.size =[self.arrayToUseOnTableView valueForKeyPath:@"Size"];
        stock.requests =[self.arrayToUseOnTableView valueForKeyPath:@"Requests"];


    }

      NSLog(@"Log %@", stock);

    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]){
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"saved");
    }


}
```

Comment: You haven't actually said what problem you're having.

Comment: The problem I am having is saving it to core data. I have set up the entity but nothing saves.

I have tried

[context save:&error];

and

 NSError *error = nil;
    [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];

Comment: What does the error parameter look like after you try to save changes?

Comment: I dont get one. Nothing happens! I am not getting told anything. My sqlite files -shm and -wal are all showing that they have been used recently but when I run them in my core data editor the attributes are there but no other data. I am currently trying to save when the app terminates

Comment: - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    [self saveContext];
    
    
    
    NSError *error = nil;
    [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
    
    
    NSLog(@"Log  self.managedObjectContext %@", self.managedObjectContext);
}

Comment: - (void)saveContext
{
    
      NSLog(@"Log %@", @"save context");
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {

            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
}

I have tried those two methods

Comment: You "don't get one"? Does that mean the error parameter is still `nil`?

Comment: Why are you saving arrays of properties instead of creating an entity/object from each dictionary? are all properties of `StockArray` transformable? What do you mean by "CoreData format" (CoreData is an object graph, the format is objects, properties and relationships)? have you read [THIS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001200-SW1)?

Comment: "You "don't get one"? Does that mean the error parameter is still nil?" When you said error Parameter I assumed you meant in the logs??

Comment: "Why are you saving arrays of properties instead of creating an entity/object from each dictionary? "

It started from my mysql database, that gets transferred to php, php then puts it into a JSON string and from there I have just been trying to find various ways to store it in core data. I do want to save an entity for each dictionary. Properties are indeed transformable  I know that "the format is objects, properties and relationships" (I think!) I assumed that I need no relationships just one entity with lots or rows of attributes with different data from each dictionary?

Comment: I just want to know how to take what I have and store it. Forgive my naivety but I am teaching myself and this is the first coding I have ever done. I may not even need to do this??? I have parsed the data into a tableview but thought it better to store the parsed data into core so the user can still browse contents and add to basket offline??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I did this and it looped through the array of dictionaries and stored them correctly

```
Stock *stock = nil;
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

for (NSDictionary *dict in self.arrayToUseOnTableView)
{

    stock = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Stock" inManagedObjectContext:context];


    stock.unique = [dict valueForKeyPath:@"Id"];
    stock.type =[dict valueForKey:@"Type"];
    stock.name =[dict objectForKey:@"Name"];
    stock.subName =[dict objectForKey:@"Subname" ] ;
    stock.price =[dict objectForKey:@"Price"];
    stock.size =[dict objectForKey:@"Size"];
    stock.requests =[dict objectForKey:@"Requests"];

    NSLog(@"Log %@", stock);

[self saveContext];
```